# submit button of form does not work

Tags: html, forms, input, submit

My form doesn't submit like it should

I saw that there could be a `<table>` inside `<form>` so that should not be the problem right?

```
<from action="pages/save.php" method="post">
        <table class="table table-condensed">
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <input name='name' class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo ucfirst($result['name']);?>" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Id:</td>
                <td>
                    <input name='id' class="form-control" disabled type="text" value="<?php echo ucfirst($result['id']);?>" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Product #:</td>
                <td>
                    <input name='productNumber' class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo ucfirst($result['productNumber']);?>" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Size:</td>
                <td>
                    <input name='size' class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo ucfirst($result['size']);?>" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Color:</td>
                <td>
                    <input name='color' class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo ucfirst($result['color']);?>" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr
                <?php if($result['storage']<$result['storageWarningAmount']){echo "class='danger'";}?>>
                <td>Storage:</td>
                <td>
                    <input name='storage' class="form-control" disabled type="text" value="<?php echo ucfirst($result['storage']);?>" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Storage warning amount:</td>
                <td>
                    <input name='storageWarningAmount' class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo ucfirst($result['storageWarningAmount']);?>" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Image path:</td>
                <td>
                    <input name='imgPath' class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $result['imgPath'];?>" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date added:</td>
                <td>
                    <input name='dateAdded' class="form-control" disabled type="text" value="<?php echo ucfirst($result['dateAdded']);?>" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date last updated:</td>
                <td>
                    <input name='dateLastUpdated' class="form-control" disabled type="text" value="<?php echo ucfirst($result['dateLastUpdated']);?>" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Save"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate()?>" />
    </from>
```

I tried everything.

I don't have any js with this form

$result is generated at top of the page and has correct values

pages/save.php exists

Comment: its form , You have written from

Answer (score 2):

You misspelt `<form>` as `<from>`. This would have been picked up by [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu/).